# Adding library in BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej

I am wondering if there a way to add Referenced library in blueJ. In eclipse, you can add the referenced library by clicking `Build Path>> add external jar`. How can you do it in blueJ? It is because I would like to use other library such as javax.mail, hibernate, and also log4j in BlueJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find your question clear, but if you are asking about adding a library into Java we should use the keyword import.  For example if i want to import the libraries and classes of all objects I use:

```
import java.io.*;
```

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools -> Preferences -> Libraries -> Add file
Press OK and restart BlueJ you can now see that library is loaded.

"One of my favourite IDEs out there is BlueJ"
      — James Gosling, creator of Java.

https://www.bluej.org/

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Tools -> Preferences -> Libraries in the macOS version of BlueJ 4.2.2. You need to open the Editor, Options -> Key Bindings… -> Libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Note: it seems that I can't find 'Preferences' in Mac. In case of that, press `command+,` to toggle the preferences window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for using those libraries in just one class - then you can move the .jar files into the same directory as the project file and then simply import them using:

```
import simpleIO.*;
```

However, if you are looking to import these libraries in multiple projects, it's better to reference the library locations rather than making copies in each BlueJ project.

> Open "Preferences">"Libraries" - Then add the location where your classes are as a library path. Restart BlueJ - Now the selected libraries will now be available in all projects that you open.

http://www.bluej.org/faq.html#faq_How_do_I_use_custom_class_libraries__JARs__