# How to add a .jar file to a BlueJ project?

Tags: java, jar, jakarta-mail, libraries, bluej

I am developing a Java console application and using the mail code to send an email when a user purchases a product. For that purpose, I am using mail.jar and activation.jar files. But in BlueJ, I can't find any option to import a jar file. Following is the screenshot of it.

[image]

Should I update my BlueJ or what can I do to add jar files to my project?

Thank you

Comment: Adding external jar is generally a good option, importing might result in errors though. I am not very sure about BlueJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your problem actually is, but here is an overview that hopefully helps:

When you want to use 3rd party JARs for your project, you need to do three things:

- your IDE must know that x.jar will be used by the project, that is where you add an *external* jar in bluej, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346079/adding-library-in-bluej)
- in your source code for your classes, you have to *import* any 3rd party class, so that the compiler knows you want to use it
- later, when "shipping" your project to other people, you have to include the jar files, too. And of course, your class path setup must be correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use 3rd party JARs for your project, you need to do three things:

your IDE must know that x.jar will be used by the project, that is where you add an external jar in bluej, see here
in your source code for your classes, you have to import any 3rd party class, so that the compiler knows you want to use it
later, when "shipping" your project to other people, you have to include the jar files, too. And of course, your class path setup must be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your window all the way to the right, the buttons are hidden over there.  It's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to Extract the .jar file into the library folder of BlueJ. 
Then goto to  Tools option, then Preferences option, then choose Libraries
& then Add File then select .jar file from BlueJ/lib/userlib/__.jar